# jQuery - Select tag , then child tag with text, then sibling tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have some html that looks like this:

```
<dl>
    <dt>Label 1</dt>
        <dd>
            Yadda yadda yadda
        </dd>
    <dt>Label 2</dt>
```

I would like to get at the text that says "Yadda yadda yadda".  I figure I need to tell jQuery to do something like "Select  tag where the parent is a  tag that contains the text "Label 1".

What is a good way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not the parent tag, it is the previous sibling. You can do:

```
var text = $('dt:contains("Label 1")').next().text();
```

Of course this would also select any other `dt` element that contains the text `Label 1`.

If the element is always the first `dd` element, you can also do:

```
var text = $('dl dd').eq(0).text();
```

Comment: Is the syntax any different if instead of the search inside $(), it is inside an element.find()?

Comment: @Shaz: I think in valid HTML, a `dt` element has always to be followed by a `dd` element.

Comment: Never used `dt` or `dd` so I'll just be quiet now. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$("dl dd");
```

Example: http://fiddle.jshell.net/gE5RR/1/